# Angular Mock Inject throws error without message using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, angular-mock

Using the `angular.mock.inject(...)` function when trying to unit test an Angular (Ionic) 1 application throws the following error. The strange thing is that there is no specific error message, making particularly hard to debug. No matter what I try, it always seems to throw this same non-descript error without any message.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) LoginController should pass FAILED
    bower_components/angular/angular.js:4527:53
    forEach@bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:24
    loadModules@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4487:12
    createInjector@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4409:30
    WorkFn@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3160:60
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
```

Removing the call to `angular.mock.inject()` allows the test to pass.

Here's the test in question:

```
describe('LoginController', function() {

  var scope;
  var controller;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mCommonJobs'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $controller('LoginController', {
          $scope: scope
      });
  }));

  it('should pass', function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

My bower dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-resource": "#1.5.0",
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.3.2",
    "ngCordova": "^0.1.27-alpha",
    "ng-cordova-oauth": "^0.3.0",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.5.x"
  }
```

And the files set in the Karma test config:

```
files: [
  //Angular source
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'bower_components/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
  'bower_components/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js',
  'bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js',
  'bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
  //App code
  'app/**/*.module.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  'app/*.js',
  //Test files
  'test/**/*.test.js'
],
```

Comment: Your `angular-mocks.js` version should be exactly the same as your `angular.js` version. Your bower `resolutions` config is forcing Angular to version `1.5.x`

Comment: @Phil I changed the version of `angular-mocks` to `^1.5.2`. Same error. I'll update the question.

Comment: Did you re-run `bower install`?

Comment: Yup, I `rm -rf bower_components` and `bower install`.

Comment: Humour me and use fixed versions for all the Angular related dependencies, eg `"angular": "1.5.2", "angular-resource": "1.5.2", "angular-mocks": "1.5.2"`, etc

Comment: FYI, you can (and should) make `angular-mocks` a `devDependencies` entry

Comment: Exactly version `1.5.2` for `angular`, `angular-resource` and `angular-mocks` still results in the same error (believe it or not). Thanks for the `devDependencies` suggestion, I'll do that.

Comment: @Phil found the solution, posting below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by not including all of `ionic.bundle.js` in the `files` config of karma, but by specifically including its parts.

I also explicitly forced all versions of angular-related dependencies to be the same version (special thanks to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) in the comments.).

---

In the end, my `bower.json` had:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-resource": "1.5.2",
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.3.2",
    "ngCordova": "^0.1.27-alpha",
    "ng-cordova-oauth": "^0.3.0",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.2"
  },
```

and my karma config looked like:

```
files: [
  //Angular source
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'bower_components/ionic/js/ionic.js',
  'bower_components/ionic/js/ionic-angular.js',
  'bower_components/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js',
  'bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js',
  'bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js',
  //App code
  'app/**/*.module.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  'app/*.js',
  //Test files
  'test/**/*.test.js'
],
```